# How to select only one radio button in CardView in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to select only one radio button at a time from the list produced by cardView. I have tried many answers including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092991/only-select-only-one-radio-button-from-listview). But none of these seems to be working. Here is my code
**group_list_item.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
android:elevation="1dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">
    <TextView
        android:text="Description"
        android:id="@+id/owner"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username" />
    <RadioButton
        android:text="Select"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**CustomGroupAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomGroupAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomGroupAdapter.MyVH>{
private int selectedPosition = -1;
View view;
Context context;
private List<GroupDataModel> dataModels;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public CustomGroupAdapter(Context context, List<GroupDataModel> data){
    this.context = context;
    this.dataModels = data;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public MyVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_item, parent, false);
    MyVH myVH = new MyVH(view);
    return myVH;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataModels.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyVH holder, final int position) {

    GroupDataModel dataModel = dataModels.get(position);
    holder.setData(dataModel, position);
    final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (selectedPosition == -1) {
                radioButton.setChecked(position == getItemCount() - 1);
            } else {
                radioButton.setChecked(selectedPosition == position);
            }
        }
    });
}
class MyVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView name;
    TextView owner;
    int postion;
    GroupDataModel dataModel;
    public MyVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        owner = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.owner);
    }
    public void setData(GroupDataModel dataModel, int position) {
        this.name.setText(dataModel.getName());
        this.owner.setText(dataModel.getOwner());
        this.postion = position;
        this.dataModel = dataModel;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `RadioButton`s are usually used inside a `RadioGroup`. If there is only one `RadioButton` you are better off using a `CheckBox`

Comment: you have to check for every card view that if there is other card radio is selected then remove that one and check current. after that notifyitem for both card

Comment: @Veneed Reddy. There is only one radio button in single item. But because there are more than one items. I can't use CheckBox because I need to select only one item at a time.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel I am trying to do the same, but unable to do that. You can see my try in the code.

Comment: I solve your problem tomorrow,  till then try

Comment: @DivyeshPatel trying  :)

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: Yes, and I have posted the solution below.

Comment: great............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing and testing code, I got one which works. It is actually from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092991/only-select-only-one-radio-button-from-listview) But I have used it for cardView.

```
public class CustomGroupAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomGroupAdapter.MyVH>{
RadioButton radioButton;
View view;
Context context;
private List<GroupDataModel> dataModels;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public CustomGroupAdapter(Context context, List<GroupDataModel> data){
    this.context = context;
    this.dataModels = data;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public MyVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_item, parent, false);
    MyVH myVH = new MyVH(view);
    return myVH;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataModels.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyVH holder, final int position) {

    GroupDataModel dataModel = dataModels.get(position);
    holder.setData(dataModel, position);
    holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(radioButton == null){
                radioButton = (RadioButton) v;
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }
        if(radioButton== v)
                return;
        radioButton.setChecked(false);
        ((RadioButton)v).setChecked(true);
        radioButton = (RadioButton)v;
    }
    });
}
class MyVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView name;
    TextView owner;
    int postion;
    GroupDataModel dataModel;
    public MyVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        owner = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.owner);
    }
    public void setData(GroupDataModel dataModel, int position) {
        this.name.setText(dataModel.getName());
        this.owner.setText(dataModel.getOwner());
        this.postion = position;
        this.dataModel = dataModel;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have to add boolean in your model class and check on radio check change listner and set position wise flag in your list and then notify adapter